# Converting multi-class labels into binary labels based on the intersected elements in the train and test sets

Tags: python, mapping, train-test-split

Let me explain my problem using an example. Lets say I have an array of multi-class labels `y_labels = [ 0  1  2  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  7  7  7  7  9  8  8 10 10 11 14 14 12 12 12 13 15 16 17]`. I split this into train and test sets using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`. I get `y_train = [ 7  0  2  8  4 14  5 13  8 15 12  2  9 16  4  6 10 14 12 10  7 11  7  3]` and `y_test = [12  2 17  7  1  7]`. Then I compute intersection of `y_train` and `y_test` and initialised as `y_intersect = np.array(list(set(y_train).intersection(y_test)))` so I get `y_intersect = [ 2 12  7]`.

Now I need to map all elements of `y_intersect` to `1` and all the common (or intersected) elements in `y_train` and `y_test` need to be replaced by `1` and rest will be replaced by `0`.

I tried in the following way but did not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
y_train_b = []
y_test_b = []
for i in y_intersect:
    for j in y_test:
        if i==j:
            j=1
        else:
            j=0
        y_test_b.append(j)  
print(y_test_b)
```

Output y_train_b and y_test_b will be as follows.

```
y_train_b = [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
y_test_b = [1 1 0 1 0 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin):

```
y_train = np.isin(y_train, y_intersect).astype(int)
```

We make `y_intersect` a numpy array here, otherwise you will not get the correct results. The result from `isin` is `bool`, and using `astype(int)` converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`. `isin` does the elementwise comparison for you.

If you prefer not to use numpy, you can just use a list comprehension. I would recommend making `y_intersect` a set for this version:

```
y_intersect = set(y_intersect)
y_train = [1 if element in y_intersect else 0 for element in y_train]
```

Looping through an iterable to check for membership is handled by the `in` keyword.